# jQuery: give each <figure> parent the same width as its <img> child

Tags: jquery, html, css

Each image **container** (figure) needs to take the **width** of the **image** (img) it contains and place a (figcaption) with the same width as the container.

If I use only one container it works but when I use **multiple figures** it sets every figure with the size of the first image.

So I'm making a logical mistake in the foreach loop, but can't find a solution. Any help? I'm pretty new in jQuery.

```
<figure><img><figcaption></figcaption></figure>
<figure><img><figcaption></figcaption></figure>
<figure><img><figcaption></figcaption></figure>

<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
    //make figure the width of its image child
    $('figure').each(function() {
    var childWidth = $('figure img').width();
    console.log(childWidth);
    $('figure').width(childWidth);
    })
});
<script>
```

[look at the html/css code](http://www.rogez.design/index.php?page=webdesign)

Comment: You know you can do this with CSS...right?

Comment: Only the opposite way no? All images have a different width and the container needs to take over this custom width. If I'm wrong please tell me how?

Comment: See this question and answer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884416/is-it-possible-to-wrap-the-contents-of-this-div-based-on-one-element-over-anothe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting and setting all `figure` elements `width` within `.each()`. Substitute

```
var childWidth = $("img", this).width(); // selects current `figure` `img`
```

for

```
var childWidth = $('figure img').width(); // selects all `img` elements
```

and

```
$(this).width(childWidth); // selects current `figure`
```

for

```
$('figure').width(childWidth); // selects all `figure` elements
```

Comment: Man, that fixed it! I never knew you could use a second argument **this** into a **$** selector like: '$("img", this)'. I'm grateful.

Comment: @Kleajmp _"I never knew you could use a second argument this into a $ selector like: '$("img", this)'."_ See [`jQuery( selector [, context ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context)

Comment: yes, designers who try to use scripting... don't understand what they meant with 'context'. But now I do! Thanks again for the clear explanation. I'll write this on my wall.